What was IBM VS/PC?
I found this 1976 Digital internal memorandum which is a competitive evaluation of IBM mainframes versus Digital's DECsystem-10 machines. Page 7 says the following:

In 1976 IBM announced VS/PC which was built as a person-computing, time-sharing option to OS/VS. The significant features of this announcement were a computer system with a simplified, human-engineered interface comparable to what we tout in RSTS, and a notable software evolution in shared code processors for FORTRAN and BASIC, and the first IBM implementation of a shared APL processor. The value of shared processors in interactive applications is the substantial decrease in the amount of real memory required to support the application.

I have never heard of this "VS/PC" before and am wondering what it is. A "time-sharing option to OS/VS" sounds like TSO, but TSO was released in 1971, not 1976. Possibly, 1976 was the release date of TSO/E, but I've never heard TSO/E called "VS/PC" before.
And then I discover a manual for it on Bitsavers: SH20-9071-2 VS Personal Computing (VSPC) General Users Guide and Command Language. And from looking at that manual, it looks like something very different from TSO in syntax – plus it ran on all three of OS/VS1, OS/VS2 MVS, and DOS/VS, whereas TSO only ever ran on OS/VS2.
I also found a Wikipedia article on it, but I really doubt the article's accuracy – it presents it purely as a hosted service running in IBM's service bureau, while its own documentation implies it could be installed on customer systems.
What was it? Why did it exist? What happened to it?

Sounds similar in purpose to VM/CMS, except without needing VM.

As for “why VS/PC instead of TSO?”, well IBM was a Big Company, and Big Companies have a lot of moving parts that don’t always communicate with each other.  In this case, someone needed interactive access to batch systems unsupported by TSO, but TSO wouldn’t be ported to older systems.  It really is that simple.

It was not "the first IBM implementation of a shared APL processor." APL worked fine under CP/67. I used it at MIT in 1970. CP/67 was not a commercial IBM product; it came from their research lab in Cambridge, Massachusetts.

"Virtual Storage Personal Computing" seems to have been mostly as per the Wikipedia article, software for a distant IBM mainframe running a VS-family operating system. You needed a way to communicate with it: the article mentions dial-up modems, which would presumably have involved VTAM. However, the mainframe didn't have to be in an IBM service centre; it could be at a company or university site. I'll fix the Wikipedia article.
The APL Wiki page on VS APL makes this clearer: batch-mode APL doesn't make sense, so this allowed use of APL without going to a mainframe.
The reason this was innovative is that much IBM mainframe software wasn't set up for access from terminals at the time. It worked in terms of punched cards, or emulated card-style i/o using tape or disk drives. VS/PC provided remote terminal facilities. In the mid-1980s, VS/PC was replaced by TSO.

I don't think this answer is correct. I found this 1984 article about IBM forcing VSPC customers to migrate TSO, which makes clear it was an alternative to TSO – see PDF page 48 of http://www.bitsavers.org/magazines/Datamation/19841015.pdf – whereas what you are talking about sounds more like some kind of networking software, like VTAM. ACF/VTAM manual mentions VSPC which implies VSPC used VTAM – see PDF page 43 of https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/sna/acf/GC38-0254-1_ACF_VTAM_General_Information_Aug1977.pdf

@SimonKissane: OK, I wasn't clear. How's this?

“ The reason this was innovative is that much IBM mainframe software wasn't set up for access from terminals at the time”-I mean TSO, CMS, CICS, IMS DC, ALCS/TPF already existed. I think the innovative part was an IBM Program Product programmer-oriented (as opposed to transaction-oriented as in CICS/IMS/TPF) time sharing environment for OS/VS1 and DOS. Other vendors offered that but not IBM. For OS/VS2, possibly VSPC used less resources than TSO did, and hence could support more users
